# Can't exactly understand a statement (Spaß und Freude vermitteln? and etc.)

Tags: expression, interpretation

> Dieses Buch wird Ihnen Spaß und Freude am Entwickeln und Aufbauen – dem Basteln – elektronischer Schaltungen vermitteln und Sie animieren, aktiv und kreativ eigene Ideen zu verwirklichen.

This translates to (by google translater) :

> This book will give you fun and joy in developing and building - tinkering - electronic circuits and animate you to actively and creatively realize your own ideas.

*"Dem Basteln"* is dative, so it sounds like *"in tinkering".*
I can't exactly understand how *"Spaß und Freude"* is connected with *"elektronischer Schaltungen vermitteln".* Are *"Spaß und Freude"* the object word of *"vermitteln"?* And *"am Entwickeln und Aufbauen elektronischer Schaltungen"* is interpreted as *"developing and building of electronic circuits"?* (*"Dem Basteln"* is inserted.) Having asked it, I almost feel my understanding is correct but I would be grateful if someone can confirm it.
Thank you!

Comment: Let's take a look at related sentences, you'll probably get it from there:

>Ich habe Spaß am Fußballspielen 

>Das Buch vermittelt mir Spaß

Comment: I see. so Spß was the object word of vermitteln. Thank! I'm relieved my understanding isn't so bad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Dieses Buch = this book
  Subject
- wird vermitteln = will bring (literal: will convey)
  Prädikat
- Ihnen = to you
  Dativobjekt
- Spaß und Freude = fun and joy
  Akkusativobject

> Dieses Buch wird Ihnen Spaß und Freude vermitteln.
> <sup>This book will bring you fun and joy.</sup>

- am Entwickeln und Aufbauen = in developing and building (literal: at the developing ...)
  adverbiale Bestimmung
- an dem (=am) Basteln = in crafting, in tinkering
  adverbiale Bestimmung

> Dieses Buch wird Ihnen Spaß und Freude am Entwickeln und Aufbauen vermitteln.
> <sup>This book will bring you fun and joy in developing and building.</sup>

> Dieses Buch wird Ihnen Spaß und Freude am Basteln vermitteln.
> <sup>This book will bring you fun and joy in tinkering.</sup>

> Dieses Buch wird Ihnen Spaß und Freude am Entwickeln und Aufbauen und am Basteln vermitteln.
> <sup>This book will bring you fun and joy in developing and building and in tinkering.</sup>

> Dieses Buch wird Ihnen Spaß und Freude am Entwickeln und Aufbauen - dem Basteln - vermitteln.
> <sup>This book will bring you fun and joy in developing and building (i.e. in tinkering).</sup>

- elektronischer Schaltungen = of electronic circuits
  Genitivattribut (attribute of "Entwickeln und Aufbauen" but also of "Basteln")

> Dieses Buch wird Ihnen Spaß und Freude am Entwickeln und Aufbauen - dem Basteln - elektronischer Schaltungen vermitteln.
> <sup>This book will bring you fun and joy in developing and building (i.e. tinkering) of electronic circuits.</sup>

I think the rest of the sentence should be clear. (You didn't ask questions about the rest.)

Comment: Thank you as always. I tried to see what a technical text book look like in German and thought it'll help me in strengthening my grammar to read the book. So I'll try it from time to time..